Iterating Across Files and Directories to Clean Avro Data in Python
Good evening Python experts,
I am trying to implement a python pipeline that will preprocess .avro data files across multiple dates, subjects (i.e., participants), and timestamps. Note that the data is organized in separate folders by date, and participant, with multiple files for different time periods for each subject. The file structure looks something like this:

The key difference in the actual structure are the true file names, and of course the number of dates, subjects, and time-related avro files. This is a huge amount of preprocessing to do one subject, date, and time point at a time. I would like to adapt my current script but do not know how. This is a snippet of what I have so far that has worked on a single avro file:
1. Import Directories:
    from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
    import json
    import csv
    import os

2. Create a variable containing the path to a single Avro file, and another variable holding the output directory for the preprocessed data:
avro_file_path = "/Users/ymhs/projects/01-01-2024/sub-001/Time1.avro"
output_dir = "/Users/ymhs/projects/preproc/"

3. Export data to csv File for different measures of interest. I'm showing the chunk of code for "Accelerometer" data as an example.
acc = data["rawData"]["accelerometer"]

timestamp = [round(acc["timestampStart"] + i * (1e6 / acc["samplingFrequency"]))
             for i in range(len(acc["x"]))]
with open(os.path.join(output_dir, 'accelerometer.csv'), 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["unix_timestamp", "x", "y", "z"])
    writer.writerows([[ts, x, y, z] for ts, x, y, z in zip(timestamp, acc["x"], acc["y"], acc["z"])])

This yields a cvs file I can use for subsequent analyses, but it only yields a single avro file's worth of data. Further, the resultant naming convention for the resultant file does not have the subject ID or date in the name. I do not know how to add these components to the file name since they will be variable.
I feel as though the solution to this should be straight forward, but I am a Python novice, and any advice would be sincerely appreciated. I deeply appreciate any guidance you may be able to offer.

You are most of the way there.  Python has the capability to iterate through a file structure and store the file names as variables.  You can process each file one at a time using your current code, and use file name variable when creating new file files.  The pathlib module is part of the standard library and can help with finding the files you want.
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader
import json
import csv
import os
from pathlib import Path

avro_root_dir = Path("/Users/ymhs/projects/")
output_dir = Path("/Users/ymhs/projects/preproc/")

# match the format: mm-dd-yyyy/{anything}/{filename}.avro
for file in avro_root_dir.glob('[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/*/*.avro'):
    with file.open('rb') as fp:
        # add your code to extract the `data` variable here
        data = DataFileReader(fp, DatumReader())
    acc = data["rawData"]["accelerometer"]
    timestamp = [round(acc["timestampStart"] + i * (1e6 / acc["samplingFrequency"]))
                 for i in range(len(acc["x"]))]

    _*, date, subject, filename = file.parts
    outfile = output_dir / date / subject / filename.replace('.avro', '.csv')
    with outfile.open('w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["unix_timestamp", "x", "y", "z"])
        writer.writerows([[ts, x, y, z] for ts, x, y, z in zip(timestamp, acc["x"], acc["y"], acc["z"])])


Hi @James - thank you so much for your thoughtful reply. This helps me tremendously. When I try to implement your fix, I get a syntax error on the first line of the second chunk of code
(e.g., _*, date, subject, filename = file.parts)
It identifies a syntax error after for first comma, and I am not knowledgable enough in Python to identify what it is. Might you be able to help me understand this?

Hi again @James, I have an update: if I remove the _* from the beginning of the first line of the second chunk of code, it runs, but it doesn't produce a processed file. I would also ideally like the subject name and date in the file name, not in subdirectories in the preprocessed path. I apologize for the proliferation of questions; I sincerely appreciate your time.
